# Trigger a click on first item of ng-repeat, initially and each time new data is loaded

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm very very new to Angular JS and have the following requirement:

I have an ng-repeat as shown below:

```
<div class="panel" ng-repeat="(appname, value) in chart.accordionData" style="margin-top: 0;">

    <div class="accordion collapsed" data-parent="#accordion1"
      data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#{{appname.replace(' ','')}}">
       <div class="accordion-head" initial-select index="{{$index}}">
         <div class="arrow chevron"></div>
         <h4><i></i>{{appname}}</h4>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="{{appname.replace(' ','')}}">
       <p class="highlightable" >
            Some data
       </p>
    </div> 
</div>
```

The data in this `ng-repeat` comes from the server.

So the problem statement I have is to perform a `click` trigger on the first element under `ng-repeat`, `.accordion-head` so that the first item in the list is always open. I tried various approaches of putting `$watch` etc. but when the number of items in the list are same, then the trigger doesn't fire.

**(the first item in list has to be clicked even when new data is loaded)**

I thought of writing a directive `initial-select` and perform click based on index but that happens only once. I really need an experts advice.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest option is to use [data-ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)="collapse = !$first;".

Another option:
Have you used [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion)? Also, are you using $http or $resource to get data from the server?

If you use $resource, you can set a variable on the success callback (interceptor response) to open=true. Then, you can either bind this variable to Angular UI Bootstrap is-open attribute or to your data-toggle. Also, with $resource you can set data-ng-if="chart.accordionData.$resolved" (or chart.$resolved depending on your setup), which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a watch to watch the array contents.

Check out the following fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/akonchady/w0qdsen7/3/

I have used a variable to keep track when the array content changes since directly watching the array will be more memory intensive.

Here is the main code that watches the variable:

```
$scope.$watch('arrModified', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if(newValue) { //array is modified
      //Trigger ng-repeat div click
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('.item:first').trigger('click');
    $scope.arrModified = false;
    $scope.$digest();
  }, 0);
  }
});
```